# is there an automatic way to create an install.conf for OpenBSD autoinstall?

Tags: openbsd

The OpenBSD installer prompts the user whether to (I)install (U)pdate (A)utoinstall or (S)hell. If one selects the AutoInstall then the user is prompted for a URL where the install.conf file is located. Since I'm going to deploy a cluster of similar machines (physical and virtual) I would like to capture my installation choices from the console and then use those results to deploy all +1 instances. I've tried `expect` but it captures everything and creates HUGE files that do not resemble the examples. I would have thought that the installer would have created that file for the +1 as well as creating a record of the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "Creating an installation response/answer file" section on this page: https://www.codemadness.org/openbsd-autoinstall.html:

> The installer supports loading responses to the installation/upgrade questions from a simple text file. We can do a regular installation and copy the answers from the saved file to make an automated version of it.
>
> Do a test installation, at the end of the installation or upgrade when asked the question:
>
> ```
> Exit to (S)hell, (H)alt or (R)eboot?
> ```
>
> Type S to go to the shell. Find the response file for an installation and copy it to some USB stick or write down the response answers:
>
> ```
> cp /tmp/i/install.resp /mnt/usbstick/
> ```

Comment: the response file cannot be renamed as a CONF and then used as input. It's incomplete.